# JavaScript wrap elements during forEach() not working

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have the following situation. I want to wrap all ul elements with a wrapper div, and decided to use forEach(), but something is not working properly. Can you provide some suggestions. Here is my code.

```html
<div class="mainMenu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
    
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    
    var menuLists = document.querySelectorAll('.mainMenu ul');
    
    var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.className = 'wrapper';
    

    menuLists.forEach(function(list){
      
      list.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, list);
      wrapper.appendChild(list);
      
    });

  </script>
```

Comment: Please create a minimal complete verifiable example (MVCE), including **current** behavior of the code vs. the **desired** behavior of the code. Saying "it's not working" doesn't help us help you.

Comment: @JaredSmith Although not clearly stated, the provided code does throw an exception which is why it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to construct a new wrapper for each of the elements to be wrapped - otherwise it puts them all inside your single wrapper, and when your lists are nested it doesn't work because of the DOM hierarchy.

```js
var menuLists = document.querySelectorAll('.mainMenu ul');
menuLists.forEach(function(list){
  var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
  wrapper.className = 'wrapper';
  list.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, list);
  wrapper.appendChild(list);
});
```

```html
<div class="mainMenu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the wrapper during each iteration in the loop just like this:

```html
<div class="mainMenu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
    
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    
    var menuLists = document.querySelectorAll('.mainMenu ul');

    menuLists.forEach(function(list){
      var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.className = 'wrapper';
      list.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, list);
      wrapper.appendChild(list);
      
    });

  </script>
```